# How to reclaim memory after glutMainLoop is activated?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

According to OpenGL documentation,
**3.1 glutMainLoop**

glutMainLoop enters the GLUT event processing loop.

**Usage**

```
void glutMainLoop(void);
```

**Description**
glutMainLoop enters the GLUT event processing loop. This routine should be called at most once in a GLUT program. Once called, *this routine will never return*. It will call as necessary any callbacks that have been registered.

So whenever glutMainLoop() is called, it will never return. As consequence, I could not release my memory after allocating.
My problem is:
I need to load an image from file, the book (Superbible 4th edition) solution is to put this loading file routine inside the drawing function. However, I realized this method was too expensive due to multiple opening and closing files. I recalled from my Data structure class when studying B-tree, the cost of accessing external resources is considerable, so I try to avoid as much as I can. 
So my alternative solution is to put this loading image routine inside the set up scene function which is called only once. But then I now face another issue, there is no way I delete memory because of the `glutMainLoop`. 
What can I do in this situation? I'm new to openGL so I really don't know to how to handle this particular problem. Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <cstdio> 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include "Utility.h"
#include "TgaHeader.h"
#include "TgaImage.h"

#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace std;

TgaImage* image = NULL;

void setupScene() {
    // set color background
    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    // load image from file
    image = loadTgAFile( "Fire.tga" );
}

void renderScene() {
    // clear color
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    // TGA format is 1 byte aligned
    glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 );
    glRasterPos2i( 0, 0 );
    if( image != NULL ) {
        glDrawPixels(  
            image->header.width,  
            image->header.height,
            image->format,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            image->pixels
        );
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void resizeWindow( int w, int h ) {
    if( h == 0 ) {
        h = 1;
    }
    glViewport( 0, 0, w, h );
    // reset coordinate before modifying
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    // set the clipping volume
    gluOrtho2D( 0.0f, w, 0.0f, h );
    // reset to modelview matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
}

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB );
    glutInitWindowSize( 512, 512 );
    glutCreateWindow( "Image" );
    // register callback
    glutReshapeFunc( resizeWindow );
    glutDisplayFunc( renderScene );
    // initialize scene
    setupScene();
    glutMainLoop();
    // it will never reach this 
    delete image;
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "recommended" mechanism is to use the `atexit` or `onexit` function to schedule a function to be called when the program is exiting:

```
void exitProgram() {
    // cleanup code
}

// then put this in main():
atexit( exitProgram );
```

Note that as soon as a program exits, the operating system cleans up all resources, including memory, that the program was using, so it's not technically leaking memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Never heard of `atexit` until today ;).

Answer (score 2):

Every normal operating system is going to reclaim a memory occupied by a process after it exit. Therefore, you do not need to do anything. When you call `exit`, the memory will be released.

---

Another reason why your program is slow is because you are using `glDrawPixels`. A proper way would be to load the image in a texture (you do it before entering the main loop), and in the display callback render the texture. This way, you would most likely see great improvement of your program.

Comment: Whilst this is technically accurate, I'd feel uncomfortable about the fact that the answer is non-generic to any kind of destructor need and works only for memory.

Comment: @DeadMG When the `exit` is called, no destructor is going to get called. But I will extend the answer as how would I implement the above problem

Comment: Thank you. The idea of using texture is brilliant ;).